# Webpack + react + publicPath

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have an issue with my react application that was ejected long time ago..
So I don't use the react scripts.

The problem is that the application is server in different domain with different path

```
domain.one/path1
domain.two/path2
```

I have the settings:

`"homepage": ".",`  in package.json that is used for the `publicPath` in webpack.config.js but when I build the project the chuckfiles referred to by main.js has a `.` at the beginning and so it is not resolved by the browser.

It only works if I use a specific path for `publicPath` but I cannot because the application is deployed on different environments.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: did you try using a "/" instead of "."?

Comment: yes! but with the `/` all the assets are referred from the root and not from the path. So  it doesn't work: `https://example.com/media/logo.svg` instead of `https://example.com/path1/media/logo.svg`

Comment: I found the issue. When it was ejected, around 3 years ago, the function `const publicPath = ensureSlash(homepagePathname, false);` coming from create-react-app was assuming the homepage didn't need the `/` at the end, so the slash was removed. Now I set manually the `publicPath: './'`